# Can I enable the scroll wheel while moving objects in MS Word? (Moving pictures faster)

Tags: microsoft-word, mouse, scrolling

When moving pictures in word it is painfully slow to move them to another page because once I have clicked on the picture I can no longer scroll using the mouse wheel - I have to move my mouse to the bottom of the screen and wait for the document to scroll down. I just want to hold the image and scroll the wheel to move around the document. I can't cut and paste as I use tracked changes.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First zoom out...to something like 30% or 40%, depending on your screen-size, and then use mouse to drag/move the picture from one page to another. In order to zoom out, you can either use the zoom settings on the bottom right corner of Word window, or use Ctrl + Mouse Scroll Wheel.